# 301 redirect in htaccess not working for hierarchic urls - php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am redirecting some of the pages of my website to a certain page and it works well for simple url but it is not working for hierarchic url. For example in my htaccess file, my following code:

```
Redirect 301 /Search-Engine-Marketing/ www.mysite.com/search-engine-marketing
```

works pretty fine but when I do the following:

```
Redirect 301 /Search-Engine-Marketing/SEO/ www.mysite.com/search-engine-marketing
```

then this code doesn't work at all. It displays the following error on the screen -

Not Found

The requested URL /search-engine-marketingSEO/ was not found on this server.

So please tell me what will be the correct code syntax to redirect such urls?

Comment: Have you tried by adding http:// before www in your .haccess file?

Comment: my friend http:// is already in the htaccess file, but i had to remove it from my question since stackoverflow doesn't allow it. so it is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use `RedirectMatch` for exact match (using regex):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Search-Engine-Marketing/?$ /search-engine-marketing

RedirectMatch 301 ^/Search-Engine-Marketing/SEO/.*$ /search-engine-marketing
```

Or to redirect everything under `Search-Engine-Marketing` use:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Search-Engine-Marketing/.*$ /search-engine-marketing
```

Comment: can we not write code using only Redirect and not with RedirectMatch for such situation. however i didn't try your code yet but will try it also and tell you. actually i want to redirect all such urls to /search-engine-marketing.

Comment: In that case `RedirectMatch` will be even more handy, test it out and let me know.

Comment: wow! it really worked. thanks friend. but i am still wondering was it not possible through simply redirect. actually i read a lot tutorials related to this topic and all they suggested redirect, but i also noticed all those dealt with simple url examples and not with my current situation i.e. hierarchic urls.

Comment: Yes that is precisely the reason to use exact match using RedirectMatch. Glad it worked out.